# Installing a .LDF language file

Tags: packages, languages

I am trying to install a language package in Latex not officialy included in TeX. I have downloaded the .LDF file and the hyphenation rules, but have no idea how to install them. I am using MixTex.

Comment: Can you please more specific? For what package or program?

Comment: Also, which language is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under MiKTeX, I would create a `TeXMF-local` directory (unless it already exists — MiKTeX does not create one by default), add it to the list of TeX roots (MiKTeX Szettings, Roots tab), then create a `TeXMF-local\tex\latex\babel-mylanguage` chain of directories in it, in which I would put  `mylanguage.ldf`. If there is any documentation, I would put it in `TeXMF-local\doc\latex\babel-mylanguage`.

There would remain to update the FNDB, with MKTeX Options.